# How to convert a string into a structured list

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-construction

I am trying to use an efficient notation for the timing of sounds that i can play in Mathematica.

I would like to parse the string

```
"{ab{c{de}}f}"
```

as the list

```
{a,b,{c,{d,e}},f}.
```

The idea is that the sublists should have a duration equal to a single element of their enclosing list.

This seems straightforward, but I cannot see a simple way to do it.

I could use `ToExpression[]` if I could turn

```
"{ab{c{de}}f}"
```

into the string

```
"{a,b,{c,{d,e}},f}",
```

but I am having trouble doing that. I am confident that I can solve this with something klunky, but I suspect that there is an elegant way to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Block[{Times = Sequence},
 ToExpression@ StringRiffle@ Characters@ "{ab{c{de}}f}"
 ]

(*  {a, b, {c, {d, e}}, f}  *)
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I did not know about Block[{Times=Sequence} ...]. This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
str = "{ab{c{de}}f}";
str2 = StringReplace[str, x : LetterCharacter ~~ y : LetterCharacter :> x ~~ "," ~~ y];

Block[{Times = Sequence}, ToExpression[str2]]
```

> {a, b, {c, {d, e}}, f}

Answer (score 6):

```
str = StringReplace["{ab{c{de}}f}",x : LetterCharacter :> "," <> x <> ","];
Quiet[ToExpression[str] /. Null :> Nothing]

(*{a, b, {c, {d, e}}, f})*
```